# Autoscrolling tableview content based on keyboard appearance

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode9, uikeyboard, caret

In my main view controller, I present a popup which is a UITableviewcontroller class and has a resizable textview as one of the cells. Now as the content grows and text view expands the typing content goes beyond the keyboard and it's not visible on the screen. In order to resolve this issue, I calculated the cursor position and keyboard position and based on that adjusted the tableviews content offset so that when typing starts the offset adjust to show the typing content above the keyboard. It seems to work but as per my logic now the issue is when there's a large content and if the cursor is at the bottom and if you scroll back to top and start typing while the cursor remains at bottom, it doesn't scroll to there right away as I have just adjusted a 20pt space to content offset. I'm not sure how to calculate the content offset of tableview based on the cursor point. Below is my code so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
-(void)adjustTextScroll:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UITextRange *selectedTextRange = textView.selectedTextRange;
    CGRect windowRect = CGRectZero;
    if (selectedTextRange != nil)
    {
        CGRect caretRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:selectedTextRange.end];

        windowRect = [textView convertRect:caretRect toView:nil]; 

    }


    //Checks if current cursor position is behind keyboard position
    if (CGRectGetMinY(windowRect) > (keyboardYpos - 50)) // 50 added for space difference margin from keyboard
    {

        CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
        contentOffset.y += 20 ;
        self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset;

    }

}


//Keyboard notification 
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGFloat height = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);
    CGFloat mainViewHeight = MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    keyboardYpos = mainViewHeight - height;

}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    [self adjustTextScroll:textView]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**TPKeyboardAvoiding**](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) and let this take care of all scroll issues. I myself have worked on quite a number of apps which uses this. Works like a charm.